# Migrating MySQL to SQL Server - foreign keys giving an error that isn't clear (to me)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys

I'm migrating a database from MySQL 5 to SQL Server 2008. I'm using the SQL Server Migration Assistant, and it's giving me an error that I don't understand.

I have tables that look like this:

```
Table A
  ID (primary key)
  ProductionBatch
  Manufacturer
  LotNo
  Cost
  (and a bunch of other fields)

Table B
  ProductionBatch (primary key)
  Manufacturer (primary key)
  LotNo (primary key)
  Cost (primary key)
  (and a bunch of other fields)
```

In MySQL, the four fields I've indicated in both tables form the primary key in Table B and a foreign key in Table A; I don't want any new records inserted into table B unless there's a match on those fields in Table A. Works fine in MySQL, but the Migration Assistant is giving me the following error:

```
M2SS0048: Foreign Key does not contains all the columns of Primary/Unique Key
```

The grammar error aside, I can't figure out what this error means. Is it that I'm allowing null values for those fields in Table A? Or that they do not have to be unique in Table A? I tried using an autoincrementing integer as a primary key for Table B (instead of the compound key), but that didn't seem to help.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: To be clear, my foreign key is on Table B. I put records into Table A first, then put records into Table B. But I don't want to put records into Table B that don't match any in Table A.

SECOND EDIT: I've been asked to show the code for this problem. As I told the questioner, I've been using a simple example to ask the question; my tables are actually more complicated, and I thought a simplified version would be easier to answer. But here are the actual tables, if anyone would like to see what I'm really doing. The actual fields I'm linking on are QCBatchID, LaboratoryName, Constituent, and Fraction (I used generic ones in the above example).

Table A is:

```
CREATE TABLE `chemistry_qc` (
`QCBatchID` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`LaboratoryName` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`Constituent` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`Fraction` enum('Not Reported','NA','Total','Dissolved','TR') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci    
NOT NULL,
`LabSampleType` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`PercentRecovery` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`RPD` double(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`QCBatchID`,`LaboratoryName`,`Constituent`,`Fraction`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_chem_qc_chem` FOREIGN KEY (`QCBatchID`, `LaboratoryName`,   `Constituent`, `Fraction`) REFERENCES `chemistry` (`LaboratoryName`, `QCBatchID`, `Constituent`, `Fraction`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Table B is:

```
CREATE TABLE `chemistry` (
`ChemistryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`StationID` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`EventStartDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
`SampleStartDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`SampleEndDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`SampleType` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`FieldSampleID` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`Matrix` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`FieldQC` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`GrabComposite` enum('C','G') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`EventRepresentation` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`CollectionMethod` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`LaboratoryName` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`LabSampleID` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`ConstituentType` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`Constituent` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`CASNumber` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`Fraction` enum('TR','Dissolved','Total','Not Reported','NA') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci   DEFAULT NULL,
`QCBatchID` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`SamplePrepMethod` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`AnalysisType` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`LabSampleType` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`AnalyteType` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`SamplePrepDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
`ReportedValue` double DEFAULT NULL,
`Units` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`NumericQualifier` enum('>=','<=','>','<','=') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`DataQualifier` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`ReportingLimit` double DEFAULT NULL,
`MethodDetectionLimit` double DEFAULT NULL,
`PercentMoisture` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`MethodReference` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`MethodNumber` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`AnalysisDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`Dilution` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`SampleNotes` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
PRIMARY KEY (`ChemistryID`),
KEY `fk_chemistry_event1` (`StationID`,`EventStartDateTime`),
KEY `fk_chemistry_laboratory1` (`LaboratoryName`),
KEY `ChemistryID` (`ChemistryID`,`StationID`,`EventStartDateTime`),
KEY `fk_chemistry_c_EventRepresentation1` (`EventRepresentation`),
KEY `fk_chemistry_c_collectionmethod1` (`CollectionMethod`),
KEY `fk_chemistry_c_sampletype1` (`SampleType`),
KEY `fk_chemistry_c_matrix` (`Matrix`),
KEY `fk_chemistry_c_methods`      (`Constituent`,`ConstituentType`,`Units`,`MethodReference`,`MethodNumber`),
KEY `fk_chemistry_sampleprepmethod1` (`SamplePrepMethod`),
KEY `fk_chemistry_analysistype` (`AnalysisType`),
KEY `fk_chemistry_analytetype` (`AnalyteType`),
KEY `fk_chemistry_labsampletype` (`LabSampleType`),
KEY `ChemistryID_2` (`ChemistryID`,`StationID`),
KEY `LaboratoryName` (`LaboratoryName`,`Constituent`,`Fraction`,`QCBatchID`),
KEY `QCBatchID_4` (`QCBatchID`,`LaboratoryName`,`Constituent`,`Fraction`),
KEY `LaboratoryName_4` (`LaboratoryName`,`QCBatchID`,`Constituent`,`Fraction`),
CONSTRAINT `chemistry_analysistype` FOREIGN KEY (`AnalysisType`) REFERENCES   `c_analysistype` (`AnalysisType`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `chemistry_ibfk_10` FOREIGN KEY (`SamplePrepMethod`) REFERENCES `c_sampleprepmethod` (`SamplePrepMethod`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `chemistry_ibfk_11` FOREIGN KEY (`Constituent`, `ConstituentType`, `Units`, `MethodReference`, `MethodNumber`) REFERENCES `c_methods` (`Constituent`, `ConstituentType`, `Units`, `MethodReference`, `MethodNumber`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON   UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `chemistry_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`AnalyteType`) REFERENCES `c_analytetype` (`AnalyteType`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `chemistry_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`CollectionMethod`) REFERENCES `c_collectionmethod` (`CollectionMethod`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `chemistry_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`EventRepresentation`) REFERENCES `c_eventrepresentation` (`EventRepresentation`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `chemistry_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`Matrix`) REFERENCES `c_matrix` (`Matrix`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `chemistry_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`SampleType`) REFERENCES `c_sampletype` (`SampleType`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `chemistry_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`StationID`, `EventStartDateTime`)   REFERENCES `event` (`StationID`, `EventStartDateTime`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `chemistry_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`LaboratoryName`) REFERENCES `laboratory` (`LaboratoryName`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `chemistry_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`LabSampleType`) REFERENCES `c_labsampletype` (`LabSampleType`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=206971 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: What code is the assisatnt using? Without SQl code it is impossible to help you.

Comment: You say you "don't want any new records inserted into table B unless there's a match on those fields in Table A".  This is not possible with your current table structure.  Table B must have the record before you will be able to refer to it in Table A.

Comment: Oh boy, I was afraid I'd show my ignorance here... the sequence that I add data is first to add records to Table A, then add records to Table B. When I add a record to Table B, I want to check Table A for a match for those four fields and only allow a record to be added if a match exists. I thought the way to do that was to create a foreign key on Table B. No? And thanks for replying.

Comment: Hmm... that approach does sound a little strange to me. If you only want values in table B that are actually referenced by table A then I would import everything in table B first, then import everything in table A and then delete items from table B that are not referenced by any rows in table A. SQL Server will not allow you to add a row in table A that references a non-existent row in table B.

Comment: Kevin, is it clear that the FK I'm using is on Table B? That I'm restricting values that go into Table B based on the values in Table A? If I tried to put the data into Table B first, wouldn't that give me errors because the data isn't in Table A yet? Thanks again.

Comment: @Stanton: You say it works in MySQL. So, can you edit the question and add the tables' definitions (from MySQL)?

Comment: @Stanton.  No, that was not clear to me.  According to your table structure, your FK is on table A and the PK is on table B. (I.e. ProductionBatch on table B is one of table B's PK fields and ProductionBatch on table A is a FK field on table A referencing the PK field ProductionBatch on table B).  Is that not correct?

Comment: @ypercube, I'm using this wizard-type program that's supposed to resolve all of these conflicts, and I need to stick with it. As you've no doubt discerned, I'm a noobie at this, and I need the crutch. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Stanton: Can't you just add the tables's `CREATE` statements in the questions? Your comments and question are contradicting. In more than one points.

Comment: Everyone, never mind, I think I'm misusing the foreign keys in a way that MySQL let me get away with but that SQL Server won't. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Do we have to shout? [**Show me the code**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaiSHcHM0PA). Help us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, ypercube, didn't make this clear. I was actually using a very simple example to ask my question, rather than my actual tables, which are quite large. I always try to ask for help on a conceptual level and then fix the problem myself, rather than have the people on this board just fix it for me. You never learn if you don't do it yourself. But I posted the actual tables I'm using, in case you really do want to see them. The fields I'm linking on are QCBatchId, LaboratoryName, Constituent, and Fraction (the fields I used in my original example are just generic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll keep only the relevant columns from the 2 tables:

**Table A:**

```
CREATE TABLE chemistry_qc (
  QCBatchID       varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  NOT NULL,
  LaboratoryName  varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  NOT NULL,
  Constituent     varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  NOT NULL,
  Fraction        enum('Not Reported','NA','Total','Dissolved','TR') 
                              COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  NOT NULL,
  --- more columns

  PRIMARY KEY (QCBatchID, LaboratoryName, Constituent, Fraction),

  CONSTRAINT fk_chem_qc_chem 
    FOREIGN KEY (QCBatchID, LaboratoryName, Constituent, Fraction) 
      REFERENCES chemistry 
                (LaboratoryName, QCBatchID, Constituent, Fraction) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION

) ENGINE=InnoDB 
  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
  COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;
```

**Table B:**

```
CREATE TABLE chemistry (
  ChemistryID     int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  --- more columns
  LaboratoryName  varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  DEFAULT NULL,
  --- more columns
  Constituent     varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  DEFAULT NULL,
  Fraction        enum('TR','Dissolved','Total','Not Reported','NA') 
                             COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  DEFAULT NULL,
  QCBatchID       varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  DEFAULT NULL,
  --- more columns

PRIMARY KEY (ChemistryID),

KEY fk_chemistry_laboratory1 (LaboratoryName),
--- more KEYs
KEY LaboratoryName (LaboratoryName, Constituent, Fraction, QCBatchID),
KEY QCBatchID_4 (QCBatchID, LaboratoryName, Constituent, Fraction),
      --- this key should have been needed for your FK reference

KEY LaboratoryName_4 (LaboratoryName , QCBatchID, Constituent, Fraction),
      --- this key was needed for your FK reference

--- CONSTRAINTS 

) ENGINE=InnoDB 
  AUTO_INCREMENT=206971 
  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
  COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;
```

---

For the record, this a `FOREIGN KEY` from table `A (chemistry_qc)` to table `B (chemistry)`

---

There are two errors in your `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. The first was done by you (and assisted by MySQL). You have the two referencing and the referenced compound key with different ordering:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_chem_qc_chem 
    FOREIGN KEY (QCBatchID, LaboratoryName, Constituent, Fraction) 
      REFERENCES chemistry 
                (LaboratoryName, QCBatchID, Constituent, Fraction) 
             ---    |||             |||   
             --- *** wrong order here *** ---
```

It should be:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_chem_qc_chem 
    FOREIGN KEY (QCBatchID, LaboratoryName, Constituent, Fraction) 
      REFERENCES chemistry 
                (QCBatchID, LaboratoryName, Constituent, Fraction)
```

MySQL should have complained when you tried to add an FK where a `VARCHAR(45)` was referencing a `VARCHAR(12)` but it didn't.

---

The second error is that your FK is referencing a key that is neither `PRIMARY` nor `UNIQUE`. Another assistance by MySQL to screw things by allowing an FK to a non-unique column-compound.

So, you should have either (case-1) declared that key as `UNIQUE` in table `chemistry` or (case-2) your FK should be the other way around, from table `B` to `A` (which already has a `PRIMARY KEY` on this compound).

Which of the two is correct, depends on the relationships of your data:

Does every `chemistry` have 0 or 1 `chemistry_qc`? That's case-1 (and you have a `1:1` relationship or to be more exact a `0..1 :: 1`).

Does every `chemistry_qc` have 0 or more `chemistry`? That's case-2 (and you have a common `1:n` relationship, a `1 :: 0..n` in the above notation).

---

Finally, it should be clear that what caused the migration error was that the wizard you used, was (correctly) expecting a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to reference a `PRIMARY` or a `UNIQUE` compound.

Comment: Hey @ypercube, loaded your solution into a schema to test. I understand your comments. My chemistry table will have duplicates => can't make unique, but I'll reorganize my data to work around this issue. To address your last point, yes, my original problem was that the wizard spotted poorly-coded tables where MySQL has been too forgiving. I learned a couple of valuable things today about foreign keys, thanks again for your time and for the free education. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The error itself is just saying that your FK does not contain all four columns that make up your PK for table B. Double check your FK specification and see if it has all four.

Having said that, @Kevin's comment (in the question) is correct, FK doesn't work that way, you have to insert in the PK table first.

EDIT: Now that I see the FK is on table B not A (according to your comments and edit) this is the problem, you have an FK in table B referencing A, however the PK on A is just an ID... This won't work, the FK on table B and the PK on the table it's referencing (in this case A) need to be the same. You can remove your ID column as a PK from A and make it's key the same compound key as B if you want that to work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, WJ. Yep, I checked to make sure that the FK has all four fields referenced for both tables, that they're the same data types, etc. As i say, it works in MySQL. And as I replied to @Kevin above, are you guys saying that I need to add data to Table B before adding to Table A? Won't that give me an error because Table B is looking for data that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: I updated my answer now that I see your FK is on Table B not A... that's not what your post said originally.